# extensionHostProcess.js is missing and extensions stopped working after auto update to latest version

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I uninstalled and reinstalled vscode. Extensions like prettier,etc has stopped working. This started happening after it autoupdated itself. how to fix this?

Getting following error on start or even after restarting.

`Extension host terminated unexpectedly.`

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js'
```

I check the path and there is extensionHostProcess.nls file but there is not .js file. Problem with version- 1.44

Answer (score 3):

actually my quickheal was deleting the extensionHostProcess.js file. I don't know why it suddenly started doing so. Anyway , just exclude that file in your anti virus and check if it is working fine or not?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the setting symbol in the visual code . Mostly this issue occurs when the Vs code updates are not done  and  extensions fails to reboot .
In the setting button /logo there is a option for to #"check updates " check if you miss any one of the updates .
If not then ,
Go to the same setting there you can see "Restart updates " .
Click that once done close Vs code and open it again it will work .
It worked for me .

Or get the extensionhostprocess.js file and replace it on the same directory then exclude  the same file in the anti virus .